# Can't log in to django

Tags: django, django-authentication

I've just installed my app on a new server to test something out. Setup all went smoothly, app is running fine with a local `mysql` database behind it which is fully synced up. The only problem is I can't log in.

I've tried logging in via my frontend, and via the admin. For both, if I enter incorrect details it shows an error message. If I enter correct details it doesn't, but still throws me back to the login page.

There is nothing in the logs to suggest what's going on, all I get in a `runserver` log is something like:

```
[26/Jun/2013 15:09:31] "POST /account/login/ HTTP/1.0" 302 0
[26/Jun/2013 15:09:31] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.0" 302 0
[26/Jun/2013 15:09:31] "GET /account/login/?next=/dashboard/ HTTP/1.0" 200 2537
```

I'm clearly logging in ok, being redirected to the dashboard, then bounced straight back to login.

I'm stumped as to where to start looking to debug this problem. The same setup is running fine elsewhere. Can anyone give me any clues as to where to start looking?

Comment: Please share your dashboard view code.

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal log statement on first line of dashboard view does not fire. Must be a problem in `login_required` decorator...

Comment: Do you have SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE set to True or False?

Comment: Ah, I think the problem here might be with `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN`...

Comment: @Brandon Yup, that was it. Can you write up an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check the value of `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE`. If set to `True`, the admin login form will simply redirect to itself. Also check that `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` is correct. I don't know how many times I've done this inadvertently in development :)

Comment: Ended up back here after banging my head against the wall for far too long again. You get a bounty.